# Decode Base64 to object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to decode in base64  a string to an object:

this is a snippet how I decode:

```
byte[] asBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("ew0KCSJ1cmwiOiAibXlVcmwub3JnL3Byb2R1Y3RzIiwNCgkibnVtIjogMTI1OTY1NA0KfQ==");
```

the encoded string contain this object:

```
{
    "url": "myUrl.org/products",
    "num": 1259654
}
```

I need to do something like that:

```
MyObjectWrapper mObj = asByte.somthing_...
```

best regards

Comment: If this is a JSON encoded object, why don't you using an open-source JSON parser, like GSON (https://github.com/google/gson)?

Comment: So, you know how to get the bytes. Do you know how to convert the bytes to a string? You need to know the encoding used - it's likely to be UTF-8. Once you've performed that conversion, you need to parse the JSON as an object - do you know how to do that? Basically, these are three separate conversions: please be specific about which one you're confused about.

Comment: Try to check this class `java.io.ObjectInputStream`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Mybe I wasn't clear in my question. What I want to do is not parsing JSON but convert **byte[]** to an object

Comment: Which ends up parsing that byte[] as what it is: JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
    String str = new String(asBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    MyObjectWrapper mObj = mapper.readValue(str, MyObjectWrapper.class);
```